# Rails Backup gem postgres password issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

On db configuration the db has  a password, everything works fine but when i run the command  backup perform -t db_backup --config-file /data/Backup/config.rb 
the backup just shows:

someone have any idea why the the backup gem has a issue with DB password?

```
 database PostgreSQL do |db|
    # To dump all databases, set `db.name = :all` (or leave blank)
    db.name               = "app_production"
    db.username           = "ubuntu"
    db.password           = "343xxx"
    db.host               = "127.0.0.1"
    db.port               = 5432
#    db.socket             = "/tmp/pg.sock"
    # When dumping all databases, `skip_tables` and `only_tables` are ignored.
    db.skip_tables        = ["skip", "these", "tables"]
    db.only_tables        = ["only", "these", "tables"]
    db.additional_options = ["-xc", "-E=utf8"]
  end




[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error] Model::Error: Backup for Description for db_backup (db_backup) Failed!
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error] --- Wrapped Exception ---
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error] Database::PostgreSQL::Error: Dump Failed!
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error]   Pipeline STDERR Messages:
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error]   (Note: may be interleaved if multiple commands returned error messages)
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error]   
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error]   pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "app_production" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error]   FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error]   The following system errors were returned:
[2017/05/12 19:30:50][error]   Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - 'pg_dump' returned exit code: 1
```

Comment: Maybe give `http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/performing-backups/#checking-for-configuration-errors` a shot? Are you sure the password is correct? This is a hard question for people to help with without more information.

Comment: Why did you tag this with `mysql`? For Postgres, you probably need to set your `pg_hba.conf` correctly - see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html for more details or post your `pg_hba.conf` file.